# Get Directions & Send to Phone Direct Links

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, web-applications, apple-maps

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but google maps has a "send to your phone" link if you search for any given address. Is there a way to create a direct link to google maps in this state?

Also can I add a button that when clicked on a phone opens the native map application with proper directions?

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that allows the community to reproduce the issue, along with details on what you are unable to achieve and why.

Answer (score 0):

You can format a URL as follows.

[www.google.com/maps/search/eiffel+tower](http://www.google.com/maps/search/eiffel+tower)

This will take you to the Eiffel tower on the Google Maps Website.

When you send to your phone, you will receive a link which will link you to Google Maps for that search or place.

So using a button element with a click event listener you can program an application to link to a place on the Google Maps website.

Comment: if you follow that link you sent and then click the "send to phone" button a dialog box appears on google maps with your personal devices. I want to link directly to that screen. Meaning I don't want the user to have to click again once they get to that page.

Comment: That's not possible (not open directly with the pop up box) but take a look at this URL for directions - https://www.google.com/maps/dir/London,+United+Kingdom/Barcelona

Comment: Yes this actually works exactly how I wanted the directions button to work on my android. Do you know does this also work this way on iOS maps? Sorry for delayed response. I was directly affected by the hurricane and still a little displaced.